# Robotframework-selenium- Edgebrowser - "session not created - no matching capabilities found

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, robotframework, microsoft-edge

I am working with robotframework-selenium(3.1.1) framework where I use python where ever necessary.
Currently to open a browser with Chrome, IE, Firefox, am using 'Open Browser' keyword from Robotframework.

To Open a edge browser, the same 'Open Browser' keyword isn't working with 'options=chromium=true' in Windows 8.1 and,

In Windows 10, only after edgedriver.exe setting, it is throwing, "session not created : no matching capabilities found" error. If anyone has already worked with edge-robotframework-win10, kindly give your inputs.

@Yu Zhou : Thank you. Below is the code snippet I used in "test_login.robot" file

And I followed the thread u mentioned in Win 8.1 os, I created a EdgePlugin.py class and copied the code from a github location, "https://github.com/Accruent/robotframework-zoomba/blob/master/src/Zoomba/Helpers/EdgePlugin.py".

EdgePlugin.py:

```py
import importlib
from selenium import webdriver
from SeleniumLibrary import BrowserManagementKeywords
from SeleniumLibrary.utils import is_truthy, is_falsy
from SeleniumLibrary.keywords.webdrivertools import WebDriverCreator, SeleniumOptions
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge as EdgePluginDriver

class EdgePlugin(BrowserManagementKeywords):
    """
    This plugin is used to adapt SeleniumLibrary to run Edge browser
    (even chromium based version) with stable selenium version (3.141).
    It uses special msedge-selenium-tools
    that allows driving the new Microsoft Edge (Chromium) browser
    and use the latest functionality with no need to update to the alpha 4th selenium version.
    """
    def __init__(self, ctx):
        BrowserManagementKeywords.__init__(self, ctx)
        self._webdriver_creator = _EdgePluginWebDriverCreator(self.log_dir)

class _EdgePluginWebDriverCreator(WebDriverCreator):
    def __init__(self, log_dir):
        super().__init__(log_dir)
        self.log_dir = log_dir
        self.selenium_options = _EdgePluginSeleniumOptions()

    def create_edge(self, desired_capabilities, remote_url, options=None, service_log_path=None,
                    executable_path='msedgedriver.exe'):
        if is_truthy(remote_url):
            defaul_caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.EDGE.copy()
            desired_capabilities = self._remote_capabilities_resolver(
                desired_capabilities, defaul_caps)
            return self._remote(desired_capabilities, remote_url)
        if is_falsy(executable_path):
            executable_path = self._get_executable_path(EdgePluginDriver)
        return EdgePluginDriver(options=options,
                                service_log_path=service_log_path,
                                executable_path=executable_path,
                                **desired_capabilities)

class _EdgePluginSeleniumOptions(SeleniumOptions):
    def _import_options(self, browser):
        if browser == 'edge':
            options = importlib.import_module('msedge.selenium_tools.options')
            return options.Options
        return super(_EdgePluginSeleniumOptions, self)._import_options(browser)
```

test_login.robot
***Settings***
Library    SeleniumLibrary   plugins=pathto.EdgePlugin

***Keywords***
open browser    ${url}    ${browser}    remote_url=${grid_url}   desired_capabilities=${capability}    options=use_chromium=True;headless=True

Now am displayed with a different erro now,
"AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'use_chromium'"

Comment: Please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can reproduce the issue. Which version of Edge browser are you using? Have you downloaded the same version of Edge WebDriver from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)? The name of the WebDriver should be msedgedriver.exe, and you can try with this option: `options=use_chromium=True`. You can also refer to [this thread](https://forum.robotframework.org/t/selenium-library-with-chromium-edge-browser/172) and try the solutions in it.

Comment: Hi @YuZhou, Thank you. I followed the steps mentioned in the thread and I got a different error, [new issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66378928/robotframework-selenium-edgebrowser-options-object-has-no-attribute-use-ch).and yes i am using the same version webdriver as the browser