# Robotframework-selenium- Edgebrowser - 'options' object has no attribute 'use_chromium'

Tags: selenium, automation, robotframework, microsoft-edge, gherkin

I am working with robot-framework-selenium(3.1.1) framework where I use python where ever necessary.
Currently to open a browser with Chrome, IE, Firefox, am using `Open Browser` keyword from Robot-framework.
To Open a edge browser, the same `Open Browser` keyword isn't working with 'options=chromium=true' in Windows 8.1 and, in Windows 10, only after edgedriver.exe setting, it is throwing,

> "session not created : no matching capabilities found" error

If anyone has already worked with edge-robotframework-win10, kindly give your inputs.

And I followed the thread that is mentioned in win 8.1 OS, I created a `EdgePlugin.py` class and copied the code from a git-hub location, https://github.com/Accruent/robotframework-zoomba/blob/master/src/Zoomba/Helpers/EdgePlugin.py

Below are the versions used,

1.robot-framework==3.1.2
2.robotframework-SeleniumLibrary ==4.3.0
3.selenium==3.141.0
4.MSEdgeDriver 88.0.705.0
5.msedge-selenium-tools==3.141.2

for `test_login.robot` file

```
**Settings

    Library   SeleniumLibrary   plugins=pathto.EdgePlugin
    
**Keywords

    open browser  ${url}  ${browser}   remote_url=${grid_url}   options=use_chromium=True;headless=True
```

Now am displayed with a different error,

> AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'use_chromium'

Answer (score 0):

Its been awhile since I implemented that but are you setting your 'browser' variable to 'Edge'? Could also be that since you are using a remote grid that the way options are sent in is different?

Otherwise is there any reason you are not just using Zoomba? The GUI portion of the library extends SeleniumLibrary so [all the keywords you would want are there along with some more](https://accruent.github.io/robotframework-zoomba/GUILibraryDocumentation.html).

Then you could just run it like the example:

```
Library    Zoomba.GUILibrary     plugins=Zoomba.Helpers.EdgePlugin

Open Browser   https://www.google.com    browser=Edge     options=use_chromium=True
```